# Распарсить XML-файл с помощью c#

Tags: c#, xml

Здравствуйте. У меня в проекте ASP.NET создаётся xml файл. Потом он пишется в таблицу базы данных Oracle. Потом отдельным консольным приложением я его оттуда читаю и должен разбить назад на данные по полям. И записать эти поля уже в итоговую таблицу где они должны храниться. Вот как выглядит мой xml-ка.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SteelSheet>
  <Fuse>1500</Fuse>
  <SteelGrades>Криогенная</SteelGrades>
  <Storage>США</Storage>
  <Length>200</Length>
  <Width>100</Width>
  <Thickness>50</Thickness>
  <ShippingDate>25.03.2015</ShippingDate>
  <Acomment>Комментарий</Acomment>
  <DateManufacture>13.01.2015</DateManufacture>
</SteelSheet>
```

А вот как я её читаю:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String str = "select T.xmldoc.getClobVal() as name from Transfer_table T";
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XE;User ID=Mydb;Password=111292;Unicode=True"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(str, con))
                {
                    using (OracleDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            String xml = reader.GetString(0);
                            Console.WriteLine(xml);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

И мне нужно вытащить чисто значения которые между тегов.
1500 отсюда нужно вытащить только 1500 в соответствующую переменную fuse. И так далее всю xml-ку. Можете подсказать как это не сложно и не затратно сделать? Может у кого то есть наброски кода. Как это можно сделать. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем конкретном случае есть несколько подходов.
Я постараюсь описать их максимально доступно.

---

## 1. Десериализация XML с помощью `XmlSerializer`

Копируете текст этой XML в буфер обмена.
Открываете Visual Studio, меню `Edit` - `Paste Special` - `Paste XML As Classes`.
Студия распарсит вашу XML-ку и создаст её объектную модель, в данном случае это будет всего один класс, так как XML имеет довольно простую структуру.
У меня появился такой код:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class SteelSheet
{

    private ushort fuseField;

    private string steelGradesField;

    private string storageField;

    private byte lengthField;

    private byte widthField;

    private byte thicknessField;

    private string shippingDateField;

    private string acommentField;

    private string dateManufactureField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort Fuse
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fuseField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fuseField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string SteelGrades
    {
        get
        {
            return this.steelGradesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.steelGradesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Storage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.storageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.storageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Length
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lengthField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lengthField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Width
    {
        get
        {
            return this.widthField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.widthField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Thickness
    {
        get
        {
            return this.thicknessField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.thicknessField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ShippingDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.shippingDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.shippingDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Acomment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.acommentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.acommentField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DateManufacture
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dateManufactureField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dateManufactureField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

В принципе с этим можно уже работать, но я рекомендую внимательно изучить этот класс и отрефакторить его:
Во-первых, используя "плюшки" современных версий C# можно избавиться от лишних полей, заменив их автосвойствами, например следующий код:

```
private ushort fuseField;

public ushort Fuse
{
    get
    {
        return this.fuseField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.fuseField = value;
    }
}
```

Можно заменить на одно автосвойство:

```
public ushort Fuse { get; set; }
```

Внимание, это делать нужно только если на ваши свойства не будет наложена никакая "бизнес-логика".
Во-вторых, проверьте правильно ли студия вывела типы для ваших свойств, например, если `Fuse` может быть также отрицательным числом, имеет смысл изменить тип свойства на `short/int/long` вместо беззнакового `ushort`.
И т. д.

Теперь мы можем воспользоваться этой моделью и десериализовать ее:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SteelSheet));
SteelSheet steelSheet;
using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    steelSheet = (SteelSheet)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
```

Теперь у нас в `steelSheet` готовый объект, представляющий нашу XML и им можно пользоваться:

```
Console.WriteLine(steelSheet.Fuse);
```

---

## 2. Использование технологии LinqToXml

В этом подходе вам не понадобится создавать объектную модель вашей XML, что уменьшит код, но с другой стороны усложнит немного логику и не даст удобства использования полноценного объекта (типизация, подсказки IntelliSense).
Давайте просто загрузим нашу XML в объект типа `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc;
using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
```

Всё! Теперь можно извлечь любой элемент/атрибут просто пройдя по дереву XML (главное не ошибиться с именами):

```
Console.WriteLine((int)doc.Element("SteelSheet").Element("Fuse"));
```

или:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)doc.Root.Element("Fuse"));
```

---

## 3. Использование средств, предоставляемых драйвером ODP.NET по извлечению полей типа `XmlType`

Если вы используете новый [Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/), а я вам рекомендую использовать именно его, вы можете воспользоваться [методом `GetOracleXmlType` класса `OracleDataReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1021203).
В этом случае вам не нужно кастовать `XmlType` в строку на стороне сервера:

```
select T.xmldoc from Transfer_table T
```

тогда код чтения перепишите так:

```
XmlDocument doc = reader.GetOracleXmlType(0).GetXmlDocument();
```

т.е. на выходе получите уже готовый экземпляр `XmlDocument`, хотя он немного устарел и немного более тяжеловеснее чем `XDocument`, но, с другой стороны, работать с ним на стороне клиента может быть выгоднее чем кастовать `XmlType` в строку на стороне сервера (а может и нет - надо проверять):

```
int fuse = int.Parse(doc["SteelSheet"]["Fuse"].InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(fuse);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую это сделать. Если будут вопросы отпишу.

Comment: И вот ещё вопрос сразу. Смогу ли я с помощью этого класса так же делать с другими xml-ками? Их просто будет много. Но поля будут одни и те же. Просто данные будут приходить разные.

Comment: @Андрей, да, конечно, главное прочитайте "Во-вторых" что я написал

Comment: Добавил второй способ, возможно он понравится вам больше. Есть еще третий - не кастовать `XmlType` на стороне СУБД, а получать готовый `XmlDocument`, опишу его тоже, но это уже после футбола.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю во втором способе вместо `xml` пишется путь к файлу? Что то вроде `XDocument doc;
using (var sr = new StringReader("D:\\file.xml"))
    doc = XDocument.Load(sr);` ?

Comment: Даже если я всё правильно понял, то на строчке с загрузкой xml вылетает вот такая вот ошибка `Недопустимые данные на корневом уровне., строка 1, позиция 1.` В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Использую linq2xml.

Comment: А если сделать вот так вот: `XDocument doc;
            doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\file.xml");
            Console.WriteLine((int)doc.Root.Element("Fuse"));
            Console.ReadKey();` тогда нет ошибки. Не пойму в чём дело, не подскажите что не так?

Comment: Откуда у вас файл взялся? Посмотрите свой код в вопросе, xml - это ваша переменная

Comment: А всё понял сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Всё заработало. Спасибо за помощь. Позже как с этим разберусь возможно ещё будут темы для вопросов. Если так же поможете буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @Андрей, добавил еще один вариант

Comment: Большое спасибо, но я думаю пока что попользуюсь вторым вариантом. Приглянулся он мне своей компактностью)

Answer (score 0):

Считаю что стоит предупредить автора вопроса, что возможно выбран не совсем правильный подход к хранению информации. Т.к. у вас используется БД, возможно стоит создать отдельную таблицу со всеми этими полями (что у вас в xml), и уже выгружать данные запросами к БД, например используя entity framework. Это будет более правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, но дело в том что в этом и суть задания. Не просто на прямую писать данные в таблицу. А провести их через xml-телеграмму так называемую. А потом уже сервисом нужно её парсить и писать уже в готовую таблицу. Если бы всё было так просто я бы само собой всё сразу записал бы в таблицу инсертами и не парился бы)