# Ошибка при парсинге C# -XML -System.Xml.XmlException: "Недопустимые данные на корневом уровне., строка 1, позиция 1."

Tags: c#, xml, парсер

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlconstruct
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string path = ("");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"C:\Users\elislavkat\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\xml-sql\xx\file.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("/tIPRA/Buro"))
        {
            textBox1.Text+= n.SelectSingleNode("ct:ShortName").InnerText;
            textBox1.Text += n.SelectSingleNode("ct:FullName").InnerText;
        }
        

        
}
}

}
```

[Скрин ошибки](https://yadi.sk/i/R_xVwlvr3MHUq6)

До кучи прошу подсказать более легкие способы парсить хмл файлик если такие имеются или направить в нужное русло.

### UPDATE

Пример начала xml файла, из которого пытаюсь получить ShortName из

```
foreach (XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("/tIPRA/Buro"))
```

[начало xml файла]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <tIPRA xmlns:ct="http://site/site/site" 
xmlns:xsd="http://site/site/site" 
    Version="1.4" xmlns="http://site/site/site">
      <Id>cacc8c21-5a2f-44ac-a9e5-3d52a0ecb22f</Id>
          <Buro>
        <ct:ShortName>Шортнейм текст</ct:ShortName>
        <ct:FullName>Фуллнейм текст</ct:FullName>
        <ct:Specializations />
        <ct:Number>5</ct:Number>
        <ct:OrgName>Оргнейм текст</ct:OrgName>
          </Buro>
```

Подозреваю, что не умею обращаться к нодам с префиксами.
*обращение просто к ShortName в c# результата так же не выводит.*

Comment: ошибка возникает во время загрузки и анализа файла. Текст ошибки указывает на то, что читаемый XML не является корректным, исправляйте XML. Используйте `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` и сопутствующие для работы с XML, возможности те же, но гораздо удобнее.

Comment: Прикладывайте свой файл XML, первых пары строчек хватит -- у вас ошибка в первом же символе файла, возможно, что какие-то непечатные символы будут, это отдельно проверьте.

Comment: @AK дело в том, что xml файл отправляет организация, и компонуют его они.

Comment: я говорю о том, что если файл не удовлетворяет требованиям форматирования xml, то исправлять его никто для меня не будет. Как присылали, так и будут присылать. Задача в написании программы, которая будет работать с данными этих файлов и файлами в большем кол-ве. Как будет на руках свежий экземпляр, я приложу пример к вопросу.

Comment: Используйте метод `Load` вместо метода `LoadXml`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, помогло, на мой файл не ругается, а из тестового books.xml со страницы msdn получилось даже вытащить "иннертекст"

Comment: @AK добавил фрагмент файла.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш xml валиден, просто вы используете средства не по назначению.
Если почитать в MSDN [документацию к методу XmlDocument.LoadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx), то вы увидите там это:

> Загружает XML-документ из указанной строки.

т.е. этот метод должен получать в параметре не путь к файлу, а сам текст XML-документа. Отсюда и ошибки, ибо строка `@"C:\Users\elislavkat\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\xml-sql\xx\file.xml"` никак не похожа на XML.

Нужный вам метод - [XmlDocument.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Загружает XML-документ из указанного URL-адреса.

---

Более легким и более правильным способом будет, возможно, десериализация вашего XML. Если данные не представляют осмысленные объекты или вам нужна лишь малая часть информации из XML, то вместо XmlDocument можно использовать XDocument.

Примеры десериализации и разбора файла с помощью XDocument можно посмотреть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/680438/218063

Comment: **UPD:** Все отлично считывается и записывается куда мне нужно простыми командами `"SelectSingleNode()"`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66063/discussion-on-answer-by-----c-xml-system-xml-xmlexcept).