# загрузка файла при условии c# (нужна помощь)

Tags: c#, webclient

Вообщем имею код,файл проверяется на вес и если он не совпадает,то производится его загрузка,либо же если файл отсутствует,но у меня почему то загрузка файла происходит всегда. Таких файлов множество если что,но показал на одном пример.

```
Dictionary<Uri, string> dict = new Dictionary<Uri, string>();
Directory.CreateDirectory("anim");
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\anim\\anim.img"))
 {
      FileInfo anim = new FileInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\anim\\anim.img");
            if ((new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://тут ссылка/client/launcher/files/anim/check.php?file=anim.img") != anim.Length.ToString());
            {
                MessageBox.Show(anim.Length.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show((new WebClient()).DownloadString("тут ссылка/client/launcher/files/anim/check.php?file=anim.img"));
                dict.Add(new Uri("http://тут ссылка/client/launcher/files/anim/anim.img"), @Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\anim\\anim.img");
            }
        } else { dict.Add(new Uri("http://тут ссылка/client/launcher/files/anim/anim.img"), @Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\anim\\anim.img"); }
 DownloadManyFiles(dict); 


    public async Task DownloadManyFiles(Dictionary<Uri, string> files)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => prbUpdate.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Uri, string> pair in files) { await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(pair.Key, pair.Value); }
        wc.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Мне очень не нравиться эта строка: `if ((new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://тут ссылка/client/launcher/files/anim/check.php?file=anim.img") != anim.Length.ToString());`. Во первых вы терроризируете сервер постоянным запросом, представьте если у вас 1000 клиентов и 10000 файлов, это у вас будет идти ~10000000 запросов! Сделайте один файл, который будет содержать "карту" всех файлов клиента и только 1 раз его получайте, составляйте по нему список неверных файлов и качайте их. 2. Вы сверяете string, тоже не очень хорошее решение, переведите в число! Ну и зачем в конце `;`?

Comment: Такие вопросы как у вас разрешаются через отладку. Эту строку `((new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://тут ссылка/client/launcher/files/anim/check.php?file=anim.img")` надо выдернуть из `if` и присвоить переменной с тем, чтоб в отладке можно было проверить значение и сверить его с `anim.Length`. И зачем повторять `new WebClient()` когда это нужно сделать один раз в поле класса?

Comment: как примеру из xml,получать список этот к примеру <list>
<archive filename="AlphaBlendTextBox.dll" checksum="15149AF4" original="4F1FB93B" size="24576"/>
<archive filename="anim\anim.img" checksum="85596D90" original="C3E4BC1D" size="10942464"/>
<archive filename="anim\cuts.img" checksum="6CC2EFB0" original="0712B425" size="270096384"/>
<archive filename="anim\ped.ifp" checksum="791746E4" original="268974C8" size="1433248"/>

Comment: Как парсить XML [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/680438/222542)